# Creating points on a website that I could scroll to using keyboard arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax

Im working on a parallax site that is pretty long (like 12k pixels). I want to create a list of scrollpoints, which i think would improve user experience.

What i think i need to do:
1) create an array that would consist of scrollpoints, for example 0px 850px 1300px 2000px 2500px (as it would be easy enough so i could understand :)
2) on keydown keyCode == 37 move (animate) to the previous point, on keyCode == 39 or keyCode == 32 move to the next point
3) if its first scroll point, dont go to the previous one as it doesnt exist, same with last scroll point

Could anyone tutor me a bit how to write the code? It's the first time i gonna use javascript/jquery (or programming at all)

Comment: i improved the code attached by @Lazerblade so its crossbrowser, also made a few minor improvements http://cssdeck.com/labs/swayiqbq/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No plugin required, though you may need to modify the following code to work with input fields where you want to be able to use arrow navigation as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/lazerblade01/EDwbg/1/

You can convert the scrolltops to animations easily enough as well.

EDIT: Added animation to scroll.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jZGsE/ i added my comments, do i get this right? also what does parseInt do in this case?

Comment: Is there a new link? I don't see it working the way I thought you wanted.

Comment: Link above still goes to the correct one. The comments added are correct. If you need further explanation, let me know. parseInt simply converts the string-based array elements into numeric values for numeric comparison. Creating an array of numeric values seemed to work best as string values converted to numeric when needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach an ID to your scroll point elements and the use this jQuery plugin to detect which one is on the viewport. http://patik.com/blog/within-viewport-javascript-and-jquery-plugin/

From there, it's as simple as using `.next()` and `.prev()`.

I'll try to add a fiddle example as soon as I can.

EDIT:
Unfortunately, I couldn't make bullseye to work on fiddle; but here's the code, if you still want it. It's incomplete as I want to leave the rest of the logic up to you.

http://jsfiddle.net/NMHaW/

This should point you to the right direction, though.

Comment: oh i think this might work! Looking forward to this fiddle! I will try to do something myself meanwhile, tho ill propably fail miseralby. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give a look at how twitter implemented this in their bootstrap.
They call it scrollspy and you can find information here:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy

Comment: this is really nice, i am going to use this for my navbar :)